# Cannot Validate argument on Parameter 'Path"

Tags: powershell

Hello I am trying to write a script that will create a folder and then add full control permissions for a user.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Get-ACL -Path "C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder".SetAccessRule'('New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("TestUser1","FullControl","Allow")')'
Get-ACL -Path "C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder" | Set-Acl -Path "Testfolder"
(Get-ACL -Path "C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder").Access | Format-Table IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags -AutoSize
```

However every time I run it I get this error.  Any Help is appreciated.

```
Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:15
+ ... t-ACL -Path "C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder".SetAccessRule'('New- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

I am new to powershell and not sure what to try next.

Comment: You forgot round brackets: `(...).SetAccessRule`

Answer (score 0):

To add to @stackprotector you actually need *another* set of brackets also around the `New-Object` creation (to ensure that the `New-Object` command is executed first before passing the value back to the `SetAccessRule`):

```
(Get-ACL -Path "C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder").SetAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("TestUser1","FullControl","Allow")))
```

That creates the ACL rule but (not sure on the formatting of the question) next you then have to pass that back to `Set-Acl` to actually set the ACL.

I actually like to break it into a few statements:

```
$Directory = "C:\Users\Gabe\Documents\Testfolder"

$Acl = Get-Acl $Directory
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("TestUser1","FullControl","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$Acl | Set-Acl $Directory
```